# Javascript Success Function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

i have this function in Javascript

```
function searchLoc() {
    var a = document.getElementById('textL').value;
    var lines = new Array();
    lines.push(a);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/home/SearchLoc', 
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'lines': lines }),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            window.location.replace("/OurBoxes");
        }, error: function () {
            alert("Chiamata fallita!!!");
        }
    });
}
```

This function call the function SearchLoc in the controller Home:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public bool SearchLoc(string[] lines)
    {
        string titolo = lines[1];
        return true;
    }
```

Both functions works well but when i return true, ajax execute the error statement and not the success funtion. Naturally i must to modify the controller, this is a test. Why if i return true it go on error.

Thanks to all

Comment: @StephenMuecke i think this quite true suggestion, create an asnwer

Comment: Yes it works fine...thanks to all

Comment: Sorry Stephen. I have checked for your response and i am very grateful for your help. Sorry,how can i accept the response?what i must to click?sorry i am a noob

Comment: You click the tick mark next to the answer

Comment: Ok sorry Stephen and thank you. It was very important for me

Comment: @user5297740, Pleasure. Sidenote - to respond to a user, see how this message starts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax function specifies that the return type is `json`, but your controller method returns `bool`. Change the method to return json

```
[HttpPost]
public bool JsonResult(string[] lines)
{
    ....
    return Json(true);
}
```